# Using a JBOD for redundant NFS

Tags: linux, hardware, storage, nfs, cluster

I have a [Xyratex sp-2224 JBOD enclosure](http://www.xyratex.com/products/onestor-sp-2224) (dual controller) and a pair of Dell servers with SAS HBAs installed that I'm looking to utilize in a redundant NFS cluster.  The hardware isn't what I'm struggling with here, its the software to do it.

I've looked into Windows Storage Spaces, and it seems like it will work using MSCS, however I'm hoping for a Linux-based solution to this problem.  My Google skills are really failing me here as I've been unable to find any solid examples to help me.  Most of them seem to assume a SAN backend or the like.

The end goal here is to introduce redundancy on both the disks and the NFS daemon itself.  I know I can use something like Heartbeat/Pacemaker to cluster NFS, but the shared storage is a mystery to me...  What filesystem(s) and/or solutions can I use to achieve something like this?

The JBOD enclosure does not do RAID, it simply presents the disks to the connected server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to achieve zfs and drbd are worth looking at. Internet search on those will give you some useful reading.

Comment: Do your HBAs do raid? Do you really need NFS, or will something like Ceph's replication do what you need?

Comment: I'm not sure DRBD will work for this scenario as both servers see the same 24 disks, unless I'm misunderstanding something?  I don't necessarily need NFS either, iSCSI would be ideal in this situation.  The HBAs do not do raid-- redundancy will have to be done in software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for: *clustered storage heads connected with a dual-path SAS topology*.

[QuantaStor](http://www.osnexus.com)(*Linux*) and [NexentaStor](http://www.nexenta.com/products/nexentastor)(*Solaris*) can do this. You can also roll-your-own with a clustering suite like [RSF-1](http://www.high-availability.com/high-availability-rsf-1/).

[image]

But really, depending on the requirement, this just adds complexity with a *tiny* increase in availability. The likelihood of complete head node failure is low. Things that can cause a service outage of one can definitely impact the other. Facility environment, JBOD backplane failure, power, software/OS...

You may be better served by replicating data at another tier (*application?*) or two parallel storage stacks and leveraging some sort of synchronous/asynchronous replication. This means two servers + storage. [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org) falls under this category, as well as some commercial solutions. See [Zetavault](http://www.dnuk.com/zetavault/intro/) and the offerings from [SIOS](http://us.sios.com).